# Does the IOS CoreImage Framework support blur detection

Tags: ios, core-image

I want To detect if an UIImage is blurry or not using the coreImage framework

Comment: No, it's not trivial solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use OpenCV functionality.

http://answers.opencv.org/question/34481/ios-laplacian-formula-detect-blur-image-or-not/

I hope it's help you.